# use Theano to get the w_0 and w_1 parameters

Tags: python, theano

I have a problem where i have to Create a dataset ,
Afterwards,I have to use Theano to get the w_0 and w_1 parameters of the following model:

```
y = log(1 + w_0 * |x|) + (w_1 * |x|)
```

the datasets are created and i have computed the w_0 and w_1 values but with numpy using the following code but I have studied throughly but don't know how to compute w_0 and w_1 values with theano .. how can I compute these using theano?
It will be great help thankyou :)
code that i am using :

```
import numpy as np
import math
import theano as t

#code to generate datasets 
trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
trY = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
for i in range(len(trY)):
    trY[i] = math.log(1 + 0.5 * abs(trX[i])) + trX[i] / 3 + np.random.randn() * 0.033
#code that produce w0 w1 and i want to compute it with theano
X = np.column_stack((np.ones(101, dtype=trX.dtype), trX))
print(X.shape)
Xplus = np.linalg.pinv(X) #pseudo-inverse of X
w_opt = Xplus @ trY  #The @ symbol denotes matrix multiplication
print(w_opt)

x = abs(trX) #abs is a built in function to return positive values in a array
y= trY

for i in range(len(trX)):
    y[i] = math.log(1 + w_opt[0] * x[i]) + (w_opt[1] * x[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Good morning Hina Malik,

Using the gradient descent algorithm and with the right model selection, this problem should be solved. also, you should create 2 shared variables (w & c) one for each parameter.

```
X = T.scalar()
Y = T.scalar()

def model(X, w, c):
    return X * w + c

w = theano.shared(np.asarray(0., dtype = theano.config.floatX))
c = theano.shared(np.asarray(0., dtype = theano.config.floatX))
y = model(X, w, c)
learning_rate=0.01

cost     = T.mean(T.sqr(y - Y))
gradient_w = T.grad(cost = cost, wrt = w)
gradient_c = T.grad(cost = cost, wrt = c)
updates  = [[w, w - gradient_w * learning_rate], [c, c - gradient_c * learning_rate]]

train = theano.function(inputs = [X, Y], outputs = cost, updates = updates)

coste=[] #Variable para almacenar los datos de coste para poder representarlos gráficamente

for i in range(101):
    for x, y in zip(trX, trY):
        cost_i = train(x, y)
    coste.append(cost_i)

w0=float(w.get_value())
w1=float(c.get_value())
print(w0,w1)
```

I replied also to the same or very similar topic in the 'Spanish' version of StackOverFlow here: [go to solution](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/obtener-par%C3%A1metros-w0-y-w1-con-theano-dado-el-modelo-y-log-1-wox-w1x)

I hope this can help you

Best regards